# How to create autocomplete like stackoverflow using struts/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, struts2

I want to create an autocomplete like stackoverflow:

[image]

I know how to create autocomplete, but automcomple displays a list of matched items,which not what I want. I just want to display a form with 3 comlumn-style when user enter a key word.

Can anyone give me some hints so that I can work around with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery input tag plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462658/jquery-input-tag-plugins)

Comment: Google "jquery tag plugin"

Comment: autocomplete display can be made to show in any layout you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the URL http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/.

It would be helpful.